# How to send an email notification via power automate when sharepoint list item is deleted

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps, power-automate

I have created a workflow on power automate to send an email notification when a sharepoint list item is deleted. However, **flow checker is throwing an error that only Site admins can trigger the flow** even though I have the admin privileges for the sharepoint site.

[Power automate flow error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnJxo.png)

{
"status": 403,
"message": "Only Site Collection Admins are allowed to use this trigger\r\nclientRequestId:XXXXXXXXXXXX\r\nserviceRequestId: XXXXXXXXXXX"
}

Can someone help with the resolution of this issue or have any alternative methods to create the delete trigger flow on power automate.

Thanks!

Comment: Not Site Admin, Site Collection Admin, and yes, that's a different thing for Sharepoint. Is the connection reference on your name and do you have the appropriate Collection Admin Privileges?

Comment: @IonaVarga - This worked. Having site collection admin rights on the site, I was able to create and run a delete flow. Thank you